# Why do people prefer black-on-white on Kindle/ebook readers, but white-on-black in IDEs?

Tags: readability

Why do people prefer black-text-on-white-background for their Kindle / ebook readers; but bright-text-on-dark-background for their IDEs?

Both are instances of reading text on a screen. Scientifically, one of them has to be more efficient (i mean faster and more accurate reading, not energy consumption) that the other. Do you know which one?

Comment: Hi Noam, welcome to ux.SE. I'm not familiar on any figures that support your claim - BW theme preference - on either eReaders or IDEs. And scientifically speaking one does not have to be more 'efficient' than the other, although depending on context (typically environment) some may be more 'pleasant' than others. But that issue is far from your question.

Comment: I prefer dark text on light background for everything. I am not sure where you got this information from. but even if you can provide a source I don't think we would be able to answer the question with any proven facts. Answers would likely just be personal opinions. Also, what even is your definition of "more efficient"?

Comment: Kindle displays were designed by typographers, UX experts and graphic artists. IDEs are set up by programmers and hobbyists. That's the difference.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I really appreciate it.

Comment: subtle colour and weighting differences are more easily discernible on a dark background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a decision made independently by every company. This questions is most likely not really answerable, but here are some studies about display polarity/contrast, which could help you finding your solution.

- [Effects of ambient illumination, contrast polarity, and letter size on text legibility under glance-like reading | *DOI: 10.1016/j.apergo.2016.11.001*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0003687016302459?via%3Dihub)
- [Positive display polarity is advantageous for both younger and older adults | *DOI: 10.1080/00140139.2013.790485*](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00140139.2013.790485)
- [Positive Display Polarity Is Particularly Advantageous for Small Character Sizes: Implications for Display Design | *DOI: 10.1177/0018720813515509*](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/0018720813515509)
- [Effects of VDT leading-display design on visual performance of users in handling static and dynamic display information dual-tasks | *DOI: 10.1016/S0169-8141(03)00041-6*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0169814103000416)
- [Effects of Dark Mode on Visual Fatigue and Acuity in Optical See-Through Head-Mounted Displays
  | *DOI: DOI: 10.1145/3357251.3357584*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/336569145_Effects_of_Dark_Mode_on_Visual_Fatigue_and_Acuity_in_Optical_See-Through_Head-Mounted_Displays)

**Books & Article**

- [When it's good to get the blues](https://www.manchester.ac.uk/discover/news/researchers-discover-when-its-good-to-get-the-blues/)
- [Universal Access in Human-Computer Interaction](https://books.google.de/books?id=ZFvwDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA179&ots=2ZbBSNyIjb&dq=dark+mode+studies&hl=en&pg=PA179&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=dark%20mode%20studies&f=false)